# Function parameters within where clause

Tags: haskell

Can you please tell me the correct way to write a function within 'where' clause?
I struggle to phrase the question so I'd rather show in an example:

I could use the parameters supplied to the top level function in where clause like so

```
complexMath num1 num2 = sum * sum
  where sum = num1 + num2
```

or I could parameterize the function within 'where' clause as well like so

```
 complexMath num1 num2 = (sum num1 num2) * (sum num1 num2)
  where sum n1 n2 = n1 + n2
```

Both variants work but there should be certain correct way of doing it, at least syntax wise. So what is it?
Maybe it does not really matter and I am just being silly...

Thanks.

**Edit**

I changed the function example to make it a bit clearer so that sum function is used twice.

And what about this one?

```
complexMath num1 = let num2 = 10 + 8 in sum num2 * sum num2
  where sum n2 = num1 + n2
```

Would this be the correct way to write it?

Comment: If it *works*, it's *correct* "syntax wise"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Local Constants**

Both are correct syntax, but in a `where` clause, there's no need to parameterise anything unless it's a recursive call, so your first variant is better:

```
complexMath num1 num2 = sum + 1000
  where sum = num1 + num2
```

This non-parameterised `where` is good for if there's a value that you want to reuse, like

```
complexMath num1 num2 = sum * (sum + 1000) 
  where sum = num1 + num2
```

The second one didn't need the brackets because function application has higher precedence

```
complexMath num1 num2 = sum num1 num2 + 1000
  where sum n1 n2 = n1 + n2
```

but since the local `sum` function is only used once, it's unnecessary. In fact, in this example, it's simpler to inline the whole thing as `complexMath num1 num2 = num1 + num2 + 1000` but I'm sure this is just an example.

**Where you might want to parameterise**

If you were using a function for something more interesting:

```
complexMath num1 num2 = triangle num1 + num2 + 1000
  where  triangle 0 = 0
         triangle n = n + triangle (n-1)
```

where it gets called multiple times, that's when to parameterise.

Also, if you repeatedly used it:

```
complexMath num1 num2 = square (square num1 + square num2 + 1000)
  where square x = x * x
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it is not a good example ... my bad. But the general rule is that if the 'where' function is using top level parameters I don't parameterize it, correct? So even if the sum function used few times i can still use top level parameters instead?

Comment: @r.sendecky If you use it several times with the _same_ parameters, don't parameterise it, but if you use it with _different_ parameters, do. I've updated with a couple more examples.

Comment: OK, That makes it clear. At least I understand that both ways are correct and depend on the situation

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would say the first example is simpler and easier to read. If `complexMath` were going to use the `sum` function more than once (i.e., with different parameters), then of course you have to go with the second version.